# How to return variables or even values through classes or even functions with attributes in Python?

Tags: python, pygame

So I am writing code for a a Stealth Game in python, I am using the pygame module for it but this problem may not even concern it. I have stages for my menu where I am taking an OOP approach (I am new to OOP so please don't hate so much on my code!) where buttons are generated for a menu where there is a play and quit button. Then Easy, medium, hard and veteran buttons are loaded on top of the old buttons (where the previous buttons lose functionality) and then the 1, 2 , 3 and 4 buttons for levels are loaded again on top of the previous ones if that makes sense. However, the way I wrote my code, I need for the variable stage where stage 1 is the play and quit, 2 is the difficulty and 3 is the level number to be passed out the method and class it would need to be in. I don't know how to do this without declaring the variable with a global scope which defeats the purpose of OOP I think. So how do I? Because otherwise the code just takes input and goes through all the buttons to the end.
Here is my code, you would need images I guess of at least the text files.

```
#Stealth Assassin
import pygame #Imports the pygame module inclulding many in built functions that aids in game design
import time #Imports the time module for which I can implement delays into my program

pygame.init() #Runs pygame
clock = pygame.time.Clock() #Intialises the variable to control the game clock (FPS)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1920,1080),pygame.FULLSCREEN) #Variable which will set the resolution of the game window and put the window into fullscreen mode
pygame.display.set_caption("Stealth Assassin") #Sets the title of the pygame window for the game

class DisplayImage: #This class contains methods required to load images into the game

    def __init__(self, filename, xpos, ypos): #Method used to allow the class to intialise attributes

        self.filename = filename #Defines filename as the filename attribute passed through
        self.xpos = xpos #Defines the x axis positioning of the image as the attribute passed through
        self.ypos = ypos #Defines the y axis positioning of the image as the attribute passed through

    def LoadImage(self): #This method will load images into the game displaying them

        image = pygame.image.load(self.filename+".png") #Image is loaded into the program
        gameDisplay.blit(image, (self.xpos,self.ypos)) #Image is displayed to coordinates which were attributes that were defined prior


stage = 1 #Sets the menu as stage 1 which is the play and quit buttons

class Button: #This class contains methods for buttons including display and functionality

    def __init__(self, buttonname, buttonx, buttony, buttonwidth, buttonheight, textfile, textx, texty, stage): #Methods used to allow classes to intialise attributes

        self.buttonname = buttonname #Defines the name of the button as the attribute passed through
        self.buttonx = buttonx #Defines the x axis positioning of the button as the attribute passed through 
        self.buttony = buttony #Defines the y axis positioning of the button as the attribute passed through
        self.buttonwidth = buttonwidth #Defines the width of the button as the attribute passed through
        self.buttonheight = buttonheight #Defines the height of the button as the attribute passed through
        self.textfile = textfile #Sets the name of the textfile to be called
        self.textx = textx #Defines the x axis positioning of the text as the attribute passed through
        self.texty = texty #Defines the y axis positioning of the text as the attribute passed through
        self.stage = stage #Sets the stage of the menu which has 3 states of play/quit, difficulty and level choice

    def createbutton(self): #Method which creates a button for the menu

        buttonname = pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, (0,0,0), [self.buttonx, self.buttony, self.buttonwidth, self.buttonheight]) #Draws a rectangular button which is black and given the size and coordinates which were attributes
        text = pygame.image.load(self.textfile+".png")  #Loads the text file into the program      
        gameDisplay.blit(text, (self.textx,self.texty)) #Displays the text given coordinates

    def quitbutton(self): #Method which quits the program if the quit button is clicked

        if self.buttonx+self.buttonwidth > mouse[0] > self.buttonx and self.buttony+self.buttonheight > mouse[1] > self.buttony and pressed[0] == 1: #If the button is clicked (regarding its dimensions)

            pygame.quit() #Exits pygame
            quit() #Quits program

    def buttonaction(self): #Method which takes action for the particular button

        if self.buttonx+self.buttonwidth > mouse[0] > self.buttonx and self.buttony+self.buttonheight > mouse[1] > self.buttony and pressed[0] == 1: #If the button is clicked (regarding its dimensions)

            if self.stage == 1: #If the play/quit buttons are active

                EasyButton.createbutton() #Creates and displays the easy button through the button class and its method
                MediumButton.createbutton() #Creates and displays the medium button through the button class and its method
                HardButton.createbutton() #Creates and displays the hard button through the button class and its method
                VeteranButton.createbutton() #Creates and displays the veteran button through the button class and its method

            if self.stage == 2: #If the difficulty buttons are active

                OneButton.createbutton() #Creates and displays the one button through the button class and its method
                TwoButton.createbutton() #Creates and displays the two button through the button class and its method
                ThreeButton.createbutton() #Creates and displays the three button through the button class and its method
                FourButton.createbutton() #Creates and displays the four button through the button class and its method    

                if self.buttonname == 'easybutton':
                    difficulty = 'easy'

                if self.buttonname == 'mediumbutton':
                    difficulty = 'medium'

                if self.buttonname == 'hardbutton':
                    difficulty = 'hard'                                

                if self.buttonname == 'veteranbutton':
                    difficulty = 'veteran'        

                print(difficulty)

            time.sleep(0.5)




PlayButton = Button('playbutton',133,477,756,223,'PlayText',387,545,1) #Creates play button      
QuitButton = Button('quitbutton',133,731,756,223,'QuitText',387,806,None) #Creates quit button

EasyButton = Button('easybutton',127,477,362,223,'EasyText',214,548,2) #Creates easy button
MediumButton = Button('mediumbutton',533,477,362,223,'MediumText',560,548,2) #Creates medium button
HardButton = Button('hardbutton',127,727,362,223,'HardText',214,806,2) #Creates hard button
VeteranButton = Button('veteranbutton',533,727,362,223,'VeteranText',537,806,2) #Creates veteran button

OneButton = Button('onebutton',127,477,362,223,'OneText',287,550,3) #Creates the level 1 button
TwoButton = Button('twobutton',533,477,362,223,'TwoText',693,550,3) #Creates the level 2 button
ThreeButton = Button('threebutton',127,727,362,223,'ThreeText',285,810,3) #Creates the level 3 button
FourButton = Button('fourbutton',533,727,362,223,'FourText',685,810,3) #Creates the level 4 button
PlayButton.createbutton() #Creates the play button through the button class and its method
QuitButton.createbutton() #Creates the play button through the button class and its method




while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #Gets the x and y coordinates of the mouse cursor
    pressed = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() #Checks if the mouse has been pressed

    PlayButton.buttonaction() #Checks if the playbutton needs action
    QuitButton.quitbutton() #Checks if the quitbutton needs action
    EasyButton.buttonaction() #Checks if the easybutton needs action
    MediumButton.buttonaction() #Checks if the mediumbutton needs action
    HardButton.buttonaction() #Checks if the hardbutton needs action
    VeteranButton.buttonaction() #Checks if the veteranbutton needs action
    OneButton.buttonaction() #Checks if the onebutton needs action
    TwoButton.buttonaction() #Checks if the twobutton needs action
    ThreeButton.buttonaction() #Checks if the threebutton needs action
    FourButton.buttonaction() #Checks if the fourbutton needs action

    pressed = [0,0,0]
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(5)
```

Comment: Hi - please consider editing your question. Your code is only partially formatted, which makes it impossible to follow. Without proper formatting, your question is likely to be ignored!

Comment: Thank you to someone who fixed it for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the principals of object oriented design is to keep all the aspects of what the object is modelling/implementing inside the object, *but no more*.  What is the purpose of this "Button" - to be seen on-screen, to accept user input, to signal the state to the main program.

So in terms of this, your button class is mostly OK.  However, it's including things inside the button definition that really are not the job of the button, for example:

```
def quitbutton(self): 
    #If the button is clicked (regarding its dimensions)
    if self.buttonx+self.buttonwidth > mouse[0] > self.buttonx and self.buttony+self.buttonheight > mouse[1] > self.buttony and pressed[0] == 1: 

        pygame.quit() #Exits pygame
        quit()        #Quits program
```

A generic button class should *not* be responsible for quitting the program, it just needs to click and un-click.  Similarly for the code that switches between the Play+Quit and the difficulty level button-sets - this is not the button's job.

I think a better button removes clutter to be simpler:

```
class Button: 

    def __init__(self, buttonname, buttonx, buttony, buttonwidth, buttonheight, textfile, textx, texty ): 

        self.buttonname  = buttonname   # Name of the button
        self.buttonx     = buttonx      # X-axis position
        self.buttony     = buttony      # Y-axis position
        self.buttonwidth = buttonwidth  # Width of the button
        self.buttonheight= buttonheight # Height of the button
        self.text_image  = pygame.image.load( textfile+".png" )  # Button Label
        self.textx       = textx        # X-axis positioning of the text
        self.texty       = texty        # Y-axis positioning of the text

    def drawButton( self, screen ):
        """ Paint the button to the screen """
        # Black rectangle the size of the button
        pygame.draw.rect( screen, (0,0,0), [self.buttonx, self.buttony, self.buttonwidth, self.buttonheight]) 
        # Overlay the button text onto the background
        screen.blit( text_image, ( self.textx, self.texty ) )

    def mouseIsOver( self, mouse_position ):
        """ Returns true if the mouse is within this buttons area """
        inside = self.buttonx+self.buttonwidth > mouse_position[0] > self.buttonx and self.buttony+self.buttonheight > mouse_position[1] > self.buttony
        return inside
```

Then in your main program:

```
PlayButton = Button('playbutton',133,477,756,223,'rock1_64',387,545,1) #Creates play button      
QuitButton = Button('quitbutton',133,731,756,223,'rock1_64',387,806,None) #Creates quit button

EasyButton = Button('easybutton',127,477,362,223,'rock1_64',214,548,2) #Creates easy button
MediumButton = Button('mediumbutton',533,477,362,223,'rock1_64',560,548,2) 
...

all_buttons = [ PlayButton, QuitButton, EasyButton, MediumButton ]


# Main Loop
while True:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            break
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            # The mouse button was clicked, was it inside a button?
            click_location = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            for b in all_buttons:
                if ( b.mouseIsOver( click_location ) ):
                    print( "Button [%s] pressed" % ( b.buttonname ) )

     # Re-paint screen
     gameDisplay.fill( BACKGROUND_COLOUR )
     for b in all_buttons:
         b.drawButton( gameDisplay )
     pygame.display.flip()
     clock.tick_busy_loop( 60 ) # Limit FPS


 pygame.quit()
 quit()
```

Or failing that, the Button class could `post` and event to the PyGame queue:
(EDIT: There was a bug in this, it needed to create the event to post, FIXED).

```
BUTTON_CLICK_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1

...

class Button ( ... ):

    def checkClick( self, mouse_pos ):
        """ If the mouse-click is inside our rectangle, post a message to the queue """
        if ( self.buttonx+self.buttonwidth > mouse_position[0] > self.buttonx and self.buttony+self.buttonheight > mouse_position[1] > self.buttony ):
            pygame.event.post( pygame.event.Event( BUTTON_CLICK_EVENT, { "button_name" : self.buttonname } ) )

...

# Main loop

    if event.type == BUTTON_CLICK_EVENT:
        print("Clicked "+ event.button_name )
```

Doing this allows the separation of the button logic from the rest of the program, and prevents needing global variables.  Obviously you have a need to switch between banks of buttons, but this is not a problem for the `Button` object, it should go somewhere else.  Perhaps in a `ButtonGroup` or suchlike.

Comment: Thinking about this, a button is just another sprite (that doesn't move).

Comment: Thank you for this, I understand I am trying to cram everything into one class when that's not how it works. I guess button's main purpose is to just click and unclick. I was a bit lost on how to then to write where the action would take place but you have explained this well. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome.  Making good simple classes makes the programming easier (and faster in the long-term)